# Principle for converting dual power supply to single

Tags: power-supply, vco, dual, single-supply-op-amp

I was recently attempting to build a voltage controlled oscillator from this website: http://www.schmitzbits.de/vco4069.html.

I struggled with it, for various reasons, and eventually found this website, which modifies the schematic to run on a single rail power supply (9v). http://hackaday.com/2015/09/11/logic-noise-playing-in-tune-with-an-exponential-vco/

I've found this schematic usefully and it works adequately for what I was trying to build.  I've used 7660s and MAX1044 chips before to create a negative voltage, but for this particular project I'm trying to keep everything running nice and simple on a single +9v supply (never mind that I somehow keep accidentally frying 7660 ICs!) and I have found multiple circuits that I'd like to try that use a dual voltage supply, that I want to run on single.

I'm not particularly fussed on the knock-on effects to the fidelity of the device, this is more an exercise in understanding a principle. For example, I want to build one of these:
[image]

(Of course, a VCO needs a VCA) but it uses a dual power supply. I'm not fussed on the fidelity or headroom, I'd just like it to work in principle. Is there a principle I can apply from the modified VCO in the link above, that I can apply generally every time I want to make a dual power supply powered schematic with a single supply?

Comment: The topic is typically referred to as creating a virtual ground https://tangentsoft.net/elec/vgrounds.html

Comment: Would using a voltage divider form two resistors from +V to 0V, and taking supply from between these two as a 'Vr' be considered a generally universal principle?